# Is it Possible to modify how the raw .edmx file is generated in Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, odac

I am using the Entity Framework 5.0 DB-First approach, within an Asp.Net 5 MVC application, to connect to an oracle database. All works fine against the database for which I generated my EF data model, but I have 3 different (identical) environments set up _PROD, _UAT, and _DEV.

I have config transforms setup to point to the appropriate environment for which I am deploying. The problem is, once i switch connectionstrings to a different Schema ("database" for sql folks) it produces

`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

After hours of poking around, I figured out why. After looking at the raw .edmx code file, i found that the designer is applying the Schema ("database" for sql folks) name to all of the Entities within the Entity Container node, note the REV_ALLOC_DEV below.

```
<EntityContainer Name="ModelStoreContainer">
  <EntitySet Name="LOG_EVENTS" EntityType="Self.LOG_EVENTS" Schema="REV_ALLOC_DEV" store:Type="Tables" />
  <EntitySet Name="PAGE_LOCK" EntityType="Self.PAGE_LOCK" Schema="REV_ALLOC_DEV" store:Type="Tables" />
  <!-- Bunch more entities... --> 
</EntityContainer>
```

If I go in and manually modify the file, to Remove that Schema name from all of the entities within the Entity Container "and also in a few other spots where there is some raw sql select statements" then everything between the multiple databases works like a champ.

**So my question is:** *Is there any way to modify how that raw .edmx xml is generated by the designer, perhaps through .tt file or something of the likes so i can automatically remove the Schema ("database" for sql folks) name from being appended.*

Also as a note, When in the properties of the .edmx designer, I already know about the Database Schema Name property, currently that is set to dbo, which i see actually just blanks out the defaultdatabseschema property in the .edmx file. example below. Perhaps there is a way to set this per environment to read a SchemaName value from my transformed configs, but I wonder if this property is primarily more geared toward SQL schema, and not oracle schema, so i've been more inclined to try and find an answer to my above question.

`<DesignerProperty Name="DefaultDatabaseSchema" Value="" />`

Another note. 
I've seen a lot of references to:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyDefaultDbSchema");
}
```

but I believe this is really only a code-first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to modify it? Instead of trying to modify the files, have you thought about creating an agnostic connection?
please take a look at this [link from Sergey Barskiy](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1003101) .

On the web config file there are 3 references: 
 csdl - which represents the conceptual schema;
 msl - to translate .net queries into database commands;
ssdl - contains information about the RDBMs

All three schemas are compiled to produce the DLL of the model.

The author creates two models (one for Oracle and the other one for SQL) and then dynamically switches from one to the other.

Comment: yeah, that doesn't seem to be what I'm trying to achieve. It's an interesting way of Achieving things, but I'm looking for more of a way to modify one model, since they are exactly identical, and it's more of an Entity framework shortcoming that they don't have native support for this small oracle nuance that makes such a huge matter.